# Jquery select that effects the amount of images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with multiple rows, each row has:

- layout (select)
- images * 10

The amount of images depends on the layout selected. I want to write some jquery code that hides/shows the amount of images depending on the layout selected/changed.

At the moment I have this which doesn't work correctly and only shows 1 image each time.

```
$('select.layouts').bind("change keyup",function(){
var val = $(this).val();
switch(val){
case 1:
    showImgs = 1;
    break;
case 2:
    showImgs = 2;
    break;
case 3:
    showImgs = 3;
    break;
case 4:
    showImgs = 4;
    break;
default:
    showImgs = 1;
}
$(this).parents("tr").find(".images .image:lt("+showImgs+")").show();
})
```

Also would it be best practice to instead of adding how many images per layout into the JS code, I have a data attribute to the select option?

HTML Table

```
<table class="list" id="images">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Layout:</td>
            <td>Image:</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="image-row0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select class="layouts" name="banner_image[0][layout]">
                    <option value="1">Layout 1</option>
                    <option selected="selected" value="2">Layout 2</option>
                    <option value="3">Layout 3</option>
                    <option value="4">Layout 4</option>
                    <option value="5">Layout 5</option>
                    <option value="6">Layout 6</option>
                    <option value="7">Layout 7</option>
                    <option value="8">Layout 8</option>
                    <option value="9">Layout 9</option>
                    <option value="10">Layout 10</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td class="left images">
                <div style="display: none" class="image">
                    <label for="thumb0">Image 1</label><br>
                    <input type="hidden" id="image0" value="data/slides/dd1.png" name="banner_image[0][image]"> <br>
                </div>
                <div style="display: none" class="image">
                    <label for="thumb20">Image 2</label><br>
                    <input type="hidden" id="image20" value="data/slides/dd1.png" name="banner_image[0][image2]"> <br>
                </div>
                <div style="display: none" class="image">
                    <label for="thumb30">Image 3</label><br>
                    <input type="hidden" id="image30" value="data/slides/dd1.png" name="banner_image[0][image3]"> <br>
                </div>
                <div style="display: none" class="image">
                    <label for="thumb40">Image 4</label><br>
                    <input type="hidden" id="image40" value="data/slides/dd1.png" name="banner_image[0][image4]"> <br>
                </div>
                <div style="display: none" class="image">
                    <label for="thumb50">Image 5</label><br>
                    <input type="hidden" id="image50" value="data/slides/dd1.png" name="banner_image[0][image5]"> <br>
                </div>
                <div style="display: none" class="image">
                    <label for="thumb60">Image 5</label><br>
                    <input type="hidden" id="image60" value="data/slides/dd1.png" name="banner_image[0][image6]"> <br>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="image-row1">
        <tr class="odd">
            <td>
                <select class="layouts" name="banner_image[1][layout]">
                    <option selected="selected" value="1">Layout 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Layout 2</option>
                    <option value="3">Layout 3</option>
                    <option value="4">Layout 4</option>
                    <option value="5">Layout 5</option>
                    <option value="6">Layout 6</option>
                    <option value="7">Layout 7</option>
                    <option value="8">Layout 8</option>
                    <option value="9">Layout 9</option>
                    <option value="10">Layout 10</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td class="left images">
                <div style="display: none" class="image">
                    <label for="thumb0">Image 1</label><br>
                    <input type="hidden" id="image0" value="data/slides/dd1.png" name="banner_image[0][image]"> <br>
                </div>
                <div style="display: none" class="image">
                    <label for="thumb20">Image 2</label><br>
                    <input type="hidden" id="image20" value="data/slides/dd1.png" name="banner_image[0][image2]"> <br>
                </div>
                <div style="display: none" class="image">
                    <label for="thumb30">Image 3</label><br>
                    <input type="hidden" id="image30" value="data/slides/dd1.png" name="banner_image[0][image3]"> <br>
                </div>
                <div style="display: none" class="image">
                    <label for="thumb40">Image 4</label><br>
                    <input type="hidden" id="image40" value="data/slides/dd1.png" name="banner_image[0][image4]"> <br>
                </div>
                <div style="display: none" class="image">
                    <label for="thumb50">Image 5</label><br>
                    <input type="hidden" id="image50" value="data/slides/dd1.png" name="banner_image[0][image5]"> <br>
                </div>
                <div style="display: none" class="image">
                    <label for="thumb60">Image 5</label><br>
                    <input type="hidden" id="image60" value="data/slides/dd1.png" name="banner_image[0][image6]"> <br>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

EDIT: @Kalle H. Väravas code

```
var layouts_data = {
    0: {
        name: 'None',
        images: 0
    },
    1: {
        name: 'Layout 1',
        images: 1
    },
    2: {
        name: 'Layout 2',
        images: 4
    },
    3: {
        name: 'Layout 3',
        images : 6
    },
    4: {
        name: 'Layout 4',
        images: 4
    },
    5: {
        name: 'Layout 5',
        images: 5
    }
};


SetLayout = function (row, layoutid) {
    var current_layout = layouts_data[layoutid];
    $(row).find('.image').hide().each(function (i, elm) {
        if ((i + 1) <= current_layout['images']) {
            $(elm).show();
        }
    });
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#images tbody tr').each(function(i, elm) {
        SetLayout($(this), $(this).find('select.layouts option:selected').val());
    });
});

// Lets catch the event
$('select.layouts').bind("change keyup", function () {
    SetLayout($(this).parents("tr"), $(this).val()); 
});
```

Comment: Could you post the table HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Revision 1**

As reading your comments and understand the issue better. I have composed a nice little layout-array. This way you can store more data and basically just pick the layout with the select.

**http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/FxU6V/1/**

General idea stays the same, but little bit more complex.

**Original**

I might have understood you wrong, but this is what I got to offer:

```
<style>
.imgs {margin: 5px; width: 100px; height: 100px; float: left; display: none;}
</style>
Show how many images: <select name="show-images">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</select>
<div class="imgs" style="background: yellow;"></div>
<div class="imgs" style="background: blue;"></div>
<div class="imgs" style="background: green;"></div>
<div class="imgs" style="background: brown;"></div>
<div class="imgs" style="background: pink;"></div>
<script>
$('select[name="show-images"]').bind("change keyup", function () {
    var images_amount = $('select[name="show-images"] option:selected').text();
    $('.imgs').hide().each(function (i, elm) {
        if ((i + 1) <= images_amount) {
            $(elm).show();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

<sup>**[ [View output](http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/FxU6V/) ]**</sup>

For this example, I used colorful containers instead of the images, but technically it doesn't matter. And as you can see, the fiddle contains comments, so you can understand each step :)

Comment: Sorry my bad, I didn't make it clear in the example. The layouts can have a different amount of images not necessary layout 3 has 3 images.

Comment: Well currently, it doesn't really matter how many images are there total. You can add unlimited amount of elements to this script. However, I might get your point. So layout has some random name (example 1), that will show predefined number of images? Is it okay, if its done like this: `<option value="3">Example 1</option>` => So the option value (3) is the number of images, that will be shown? Or do you want to set some other data to the layout as well.. meaning that predefined array is needed?

Comment: The select value is the layout identifier so would need to add something extra to allow e.g "Layout 3" has only 1 image.

Comment: @John Check out the edit on my answer. Is this what you meant? Basically, you can have unlimited options in the layout-array now.

Comment: I am having a problem implementing this when there are more than one select. I am trying to change your code so that it works with the $this

Comment: Well, that means the solution itself works ;) You have to show me your code, otherwise I cannot help you implement it.. as there are too many variables [and comments are too short.](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3728/discussion-between-kalle-h-varavas-and-john-magnolia)

Comment: Solved and updated my question code by adding a couple of "this" and parents

Comment: Ok, cool. Anyways, let me know if you need any help related to this code.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your switch statement with:

```
var showImgs = 1;
if (val < 5) showImgs = val;
```

I'd probably run `val` through `parseInt(val, 10)` for good measure too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will solve your problem, but at the moment your switch statement always drops into the 'default' case as it's trying to match an integer and the value in the `val` variable is a string.  Doing a `parseInt` should fix it-

```
switch(parseInt(val)){
```